# why is inner join causing query to show only results with not null column?

Tags: mysql

I'm running the query below and it is working well.

```sql
SELECT
    stock_parts.title,
    COUNT(*) as qtyAvailable,
    SUM(shipments.item_cost) as totalValue,
    ### stock_alerts.minimum
FROM
    stock_items
INNER JOIN stock_parts ON stock_items.stock_part_id = stock_parts.id
INNER JOIN shipments ON shipments.id = stock_items.shipment_id
### INNER JOIN stock_alerts ON stock_alerts.stock_part_id = stock_items.stock_part_id
WHERE
    stock_items.status IS NULL
    AND stock_items.current_stock_id = 1
GROUP BY stock_parts.id
```

So if I uncomment the two commented lines (is a join to get info from another table), the query results are filtered showing only rows where `stock_alerts.minimum` is not null.

Why is this happening? I need all results event that column is NULL.

Comment: try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

What `INNER JOIN` does is output the row results where none of the tables have null values on that cell. In other words (from W3 Schools):

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in
>   both tables

Try using `FULL OUTER JOIN`instead to get all the records even when one of the tables has a NULL value on it. See the explanation on [W3 Schools FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp).

EDIT:

I didn't realize one of your tags is MySQL. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql) you have a post that explains how to emulate a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL

Comment: MySQL does not support full outer join.

Comment: @anderlaini: MySQL doesn't support outer joins. `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same in `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Inner JOIN will ignore NULLS when you do an equal to comparison, I would suggest using IS DISTINCT FROM OPERATOR (<=>)

```
stock_alerts.stock_part_id <=> stock_items.stock_part_id
```